# concatenate fields in JS multidim Array, sort, then create different type of JS object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I want to take an array that looks like the following:

```
var contacts = [
    {account: 'Acme', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Snow'},
    {account: 'Metal Industries', firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Smith'}
];
```

**Note:** contacts can have the same account name.

and create a function to convert the data to something that instead is an object with the following structure that's like a map where the key is account name and value is an array of alphabetized full names as below:

```
var acctContactObject = {
    'Acme': ['John Snow','Kyle Johnson','Sara Butler'],
    'HiTech Corp': ['Arnold Williams','Jason Fernandez','Sam Johnson']
};
```

I'm not certain that I'm taking the correct approach and wanted to seek some sage advice before proceeding. Here's what I've written so far and "psuedocode" for where I'm heading.

```
function convertAccountArrayToObject(contacts){
            this.account = contacts.account;
            this.firstName = contacts.firstName;
            this.lastName = contacts.lastName;
            this.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.account.localeCompare(b.account);
            });
            var aco = new acctContactObject();
            var name;
            var nameArray = [];
            for(var member of this){
            //this is where I get stuck
            //I could create a new array to hold the account with full name
            //but somehow need to add them to an array that I can sort on 
            //
            //assuming I used an intermediate array...
            //create new acctContactObject
            //For acct in intermediate array 
            //add name to another single array and sort alphabetically
            //put acct name and sorted list of names into new object
            //after end of loop, return object
```

I've been searching to see if there's a way to do a secondary sort on a multidimensional array, but didn't find what I was looking for. I've also run across mention of "merging" properties, but am not certain if that would allow me to concatenate the values for the first and last names properly.

I don't do a lot of JS, at least not of this kind, so would appreciate knowing if I'm on the right track. Any suggestions or guidance towards a cleaner way to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it will be as follows.

Note:I have modified contacts to include the case of same account names.

```
    var contacts = [
        {account: 'Acme', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Snow'},
        {account: 'Metal Industries', firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Smith'},
        {account: 'Metal Industries', firstName: 'Bolt', lastName: 'Coder'}
    ];

    function convertAccountArrayToObject(contacts){
        var returnObj={},key;

        contacts.forEach(function(v,i){
            key=v.account;
            if(!returnObj[key]){

                returnObj[key]=[];

            }
            returnObj[key].push(v.firstName+" "+v.lastName);
        });
        return returnObj;  
    }

 acctContactObject=convertAccountArrayToObject(contacts);
```

Upvote if you find this helpful.